# How to add multiple strings with jQuery in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

First of all, I apologize if the question is too primal for this Q&A site. I am learning jQuery, and I need to create a countdown sort of display in which, instead of numbers, there will be strings. Like providing an array in jQuery and setting a div's `innerHTML` to the string, and changing its class.

Comment: that's the problem praveen I don't know how to approach for this problem..

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like the below code.

```js
$(function () {
  count = 0;
  wordsArray = ["Hi", "How are you", "do you like this", "sample"];
  setInterval(function () {
    count++;
    $("#word").fadeOut(400, function () {
      $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
    });
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="word">Hello</div>
```